# extremely small gap between two divs that are width 100%

Tags: html, css

hi I have two container divs one of them has a div with an image background and i think this is the div that is causing problem. I tried removing both container divs and the gap was still here. there are no margins no paddings, and i know it is not the image that has this line its not there when i open it in photoshop. I am also using css reset [image: white space]

Where is this space coming from?

**css**

```
.container{
    width:100%;
}
.container2{
    width:100%;
}
.first-image{
    width:1430px;
    height:497px;
    background-image:url('../images/introimg.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    border:none;
}
.jamey{
    width:35%;

}
 .second-image{
    width:1430px;
    height:430px;
    background-image:url('../images/secondimg.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;


}
```

**html**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="overlay"></div>
            <div class="first-image">
                <div class="jamey">


                    <p class="def">
                        JAMEY
                    </p>
                    <p class="rip-date">03.02.1997 - 09.18.2011</p>
                    <p class="def2">Anonymous hate messages were posted on his Formspring account including one that claimed:</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container2">
        <div class="intro-div">
            <div class="end-hate">
                <h1>PUT AN END TO HATE.</h1>
                <p>
                    ANYTHING WRITTEN ONLINE can become viral 
                </p>
                <p>
                    We believe that the way we behave online should be no different from the way that we behave in
                </p>
                <button type="button">JOIN CAMPAIGN</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Maybe you havn't done CSS reset and it's padding coming from user's agent? try adding `margin:0px; padding:0px` to the first image

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am also using css reset

Comment: Can you put together a [jsFiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Add a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem, and has actual images on it.

Comment: Try to remove the spaces (or newlines) between `<img />` or `<div>` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem can be removed by,

```
.first-image 
{
margin-bottom: -20px; // or desired settings !
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be required and in my opinion would be a hack.

Comment: this is what we call CSS ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may try adding the

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

It helps setting padding/borders (maybe you have one) internal to the element. If it has some effect you can override these settings later.

Anyway, it's recommended that you add a jsFiddle so we can see for ourselves.